# String Padding, what do the numbers mean?

Tags: php, string

I have this code,

```
$salt = str_pad(rand(1, 9999999), 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Does it mean, the number will be random between 1, 9999999.

It will be at least 7 characters long.

If the rand isn't 7 numbers long zeros will be added to the right until it makes up seven number in total?

If that is correct, as I am unsure how can I change this so instead of inserting just zeros to make a total of 7, but to generate a random number between 1 and 9, and add those to make it a total number of 7.

Comment: Why not read the documentation and find out?

Comment: @Tom This is in no way relevant to my actual question, I was just making sure my interpretation of what I have read is correct, as I was not so sure, if you read some answers you might gather what my actual question was.

Comment: Sarcasm dude! It hard to come across on a keyboard lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe your interpretation is accurate.

I wouldn't bother changing it; making the padding digits random won't make your number any more random. In fact, if anything, you'd be skewing the distribution, making lower numbers quite a lot less likely.

Answer (score 1):

```
$salt = str_pad(rand(1, 9999999), 7, rand(1, 9), STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Rather than passing 0 to pad with, just pass a random number from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is basically correct. It will give you a random number from 1 to 9999999 and then give you a string representation with zero padding on the left.

If you just want a 7-digit random number, use:

```
rand(1000000,9999999)
```

If you want a specific non-zero digit to pad it with (all digits the same), generate one randomly with `rand(1,9)` and use it, along the lines of:

```
$salt = str_pad(rand(1, 9999999), 7, <your random character here>, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: how about sprintf('%07d', rand(1,9999999)) which takes care of all the padding without the extra arguments?

Comment: @Marc, that may be okay for the zero padding but it won't do the padding-with-a-different-digit requirement.

Comment: if the padding is a fixed number, then the OP is eliminated part of the possible range of numbers, rendering the "random" number less random.